# What is the idea behind Dedekind’s axiom?

Tags: real-analysis

I understood the mathematical definition of *Dedekind’s axiom* but I don't know the idea behind it it sounds useless to me and I know it is not the case that's why I am asking here and this is the definition of *Dedekind’s axiom*:

Suppose that we write $R$ as the disjoint union of two non-empty sets $L ∪ R$
where every element of $L$ is less than every element of $R$. Then there is a
number $ζ$ such that every number less than $ζ$ belongs to $L$ and every number
greater than $ζ$ belongs to $R$.

$ζ$ itself may belong to either $L$ or $R$: if it belongs to $L$, it is the largest element of $L$, if it belongs to $R$ it is the smallest element
of $R$.

And how would you determine if the number $ζ$ is in $L$ or $R$ and what is the purpose of that number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point is that it fails in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: what is the purpose of Dedekind’s axiom in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Define $\mathbb R$ as the completion of $\mathbb Q$.  Consider $L=\{x:x^2<2\}$ and consider $L=\{x:x^2\le2\};\quad\zeta=\sqrt2\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$

Comment: This is called the least upper bound property, and it is used in many analysis proofs. An elementary example: square roots of all positive numbers exist. Some more important ones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#Applications

Comment: You've basically got the wrong definition of Dedekind's cut. It's purpose is to construct $\mathbb R$ out of $\mathbb Q$, but in order to do that it's imperative that everything is done in terms of rational numbers. The Dedekind cut is to be a partition of $\mathbb Q$, also note that one should **not** introduce the number $\zeta$ which could need to be an irrational number which are yet to be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive idea of dedekind Axiom is to reflect the geometric idea that the ordered set of reals numbers can be asociated to a straight line without gaps or discontinuties between the points that constituted it. I think it will be of help to see the definition what a Dedekind cut is for you get a better understanding about the dedekind axiom. Wikipedia has a good information about that:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut. As has been pointed in the comments, you can also see the least upper bound property for determinating the characteritics $\zeta$.

I hope this help you. Regards.